# How to upload a simple web on Heroku, app consisting of Peewee and Postgres?

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, peewee, heroku-postgres

I have a  `app.py` file. I am trying to upload on HEROKU. I have seen some changes needed to be made while uploading on Heroku like adding `Procfile` and `Requirements.txt`. I have also added those two. Its working perfectly on local but on Heroku database is not creating or connecting.

**What I am doing on my terminal**

1. `heroku create`
2. `git push heroku master`
3. `heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql`
4. `heroku config:set HEROKU=1`
5. `heroku ps:scale web=1`
6. `heroku open`

Now here my web page for user registration is opening but not able to save. Please help

app.py

```
import os
import urlparse
import psycopg2
from peewee import Model, CharField, SqliteDatabase, CharField, ForeignKeyField, IntegrityError
from peewee import create_model_tables
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for, session
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_peewee.db import Database

if 'HEROKU' in os.environ:
    DEBUG = False
    urlparse.uses_netloc.append('postgres')
    url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])
    DATABASE = {
        'engine': 'peewee.PostgresqlDatabase',
        'name': url.path[1:],
        'user': url.username,
        'password': url.password,
        'host': url.hostname,
        'port': url.port,
    }
else:
    DEBUG = True
    DATABASE = {
        'engine': 'peewee.PostgresqlDatabase',
        'name': 'notes',
        'user': 'scrolldev',
        'password': 'scrolldev',
        'host': 'localhost',
        'port': 5432,
        'threadlocals': True
    }


app = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
db = Database(app)


class User(db.Model):
    ....


class Notepad(db.Model):
    ....

def setup_db():
    create_model_tables([User, Notepad], fail_silently=True)

....
....
....
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup_db()
    app.secret_key = 'super_secret_key'
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Before putting this question I also took help from here and then I updated my file [Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755833/how-to-use-flask-peewee-with-heroku)

**Update**
Its working correctly in local but on heroku its not. Please help me.

Comment: @coleifer Can you look into this please

Comment: The error message states the problem clearly: Your `os.environ` doesn't include a `'DATABASE_URL'` key. Have you set this environment variable?

Comment: I am using `if Heroku in os.environ`. Means in local it should not create any problem

Answer (score 0):

Your code loads `url` from the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable if `'HEROKU'` is contained in `os.environ`…

```python
if 'HEROKU' in os.environ:
    DEBUG = False
    urlparse.uses_netloc.append('postgres')
    url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ["DATABASE_URL"])
```

…but it *also* loads it outside of your conditional a few lines earlier:

```python
from peewee import Model, PostgresqlDatabase

urlparse.uses_netloc.append('postgres')
url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])  # <--
```

Based on your comments above it sounds like this is a mistake. Either set `DATABASE_URL` on your development machine (which I recommend; the fewer changes you have between development and production the better), or remove the code that sets `url` outside of your `if` block.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the error. But my problem is little bit different. I dont know what to pass in the database.